# How to load everything from Haskell module in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I would like to import hidden data constructor from a module being in GHCi. It looks like it is not possible for packages.

For source files `:l` is working

```
stack ghc --package ghc
:set -XStandaloneDeriving

import Module
-- ModuleName is not exposed

deriving instance Show ModuleName -- fails
```

---

Update 1. I found an [article](https://www.tweag.io/blog/2021-01-07-haskell-dark-arts-part-i/) to call hidden functions but it is not exactly I was looking. Probably TH can do more.

Comment: The fact that these are hidden is exactly to prevent people altering it. Often because using the data constructor directly could result in constructing an invalid object.

Comment: Hidden doesn't mean top secret. I am debugging and exploring library to make a fix.

Comment: of course not, I mean that we can for example create `data LenList a = Int [a]`, that stores both the length and the content of the list. But in order to prevent for example people making a `LenList 5 []`, the author can decide to hide the data constructor, such that it is impossible for people to create such inconsistencies.

Comment: @DaneelYaitskov, if you're editing the package, you can temporarily export whatever identifiers/internal modules will help you.

Comment: You are talking about abstraction for development as application developer. I am debugging library. This is different case. Hiding itself has no value. It make application code less fragile to changes in the library. I don't write application code. Hiding for my case is just an obstacle.

Comment: You have to debug the library "from the inside". You can't access internals of a compiled library at all. (Okay, you *can* pull some really dirty and fragile tricks with `unsafeCoerce`, but I really don't recommend it.)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [the true-name package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/true-name)?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, thanks, the library is really cool, but it has very limited ghc version range. e.g. not working with ghc 8.10

Comment: @DaneelYaitskov can you fork/clone the library and remove the export list?